# ASP.Net Core 2.1 Log layout in Azure Diagnostics Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-diagnostics

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1 API running in a Azure AppService, the Azure Diagnostics Log "Application Logging (Blob)" is turned on.

The problem is that it's just logging with the default format *"{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"*.

I would like to store the logs in exact same format as ASP.NET Framework 4.7, in .CSV and with information like date/level in different columns.

If it's not possible, I would like at least store just the {Message} and not the whole timestamp.

Example of ASP.NET Framework 4.7 logs in Blob Storage:
[ASP.Net Framework Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR1fV.png)

Example of ASP.NET Core 2.1 logs in Blob Storage:
[ASP.Net Core 2.1 Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ5CZ.png)

My log configuration:
[ILoggerFactory configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHPNU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need a custom logger to achieve what you want.

Take a look at [Customizing ASP.​NET Core Part 01: Logging](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2018/09/20/customizing-aspnetcore-01-logging.html) and [How to add custom logging in ASP.NET Core](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/05/add-custom-logging-in-aspnetcore.html) to see how it can be done.

Hope it helps!